# Change a self attribute only for one object in a class in Python

Tags: python, class, object, variables

I'm stuck on a problem in Python... (i'm an absolute beginner but i need to do a little
environmental science model..)
so the problem is I have:

```
 class C:
     def __init__(self, x, y, z):

         self.x = x
         self.y = self.x * 8
         self.z = self.y * 9 + 0.5
         self.w = self.z +2

 one = C(5,8,12)
 two = C(2,12,12)
 three = C(1,2,3)
```

So... i want to change the self.z but only for the object three
(i want it to be    self.z = 12 * self.x    );

I have to call it in self.w so i can't modify it after my istances...

do you have any suggestion to a beginner?
Thank you so much and have a nice day!

Comment: After instancing, you can simply do this: `three.z = three.x *12`

Answer (score 0):

A few notes. First you are not actually using the arguments of `y` or `z` that are passed in `__init__(self, x, y, z)`.

To allow on the fly overloading, you may want to break out the individual assignments into their own methods so it is easier to change the behavior you want.

Below you can pass in a custom function that will be applied to the `x` value when calculating `z`.

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, x, custum_fn_z=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = self.calc_y()
        self.z = self.calc_z(custum_fn_z)
        self.w = self.calc_w()

    def calc_y(self):
        return self.x * 8

    def calc_z(self, custom_fn_z=None):
        if custom_fn_z:
            return custom_fn_z(self.x)
        return self.y * 9 + 0.5

    def calc_w(self):
        return self.z +2
```

to use it:

```
one = C(5)
two = C(2)
three = C(1, lambda x: 12*x)
```

Comment: Thank you so much James! I tried the code and now for three is giving me the right response, but for one and two it's not giving me anything, i want it to be self.z = self.y * 9 + 0.5 for that two variables